# iText on a 10G database (1.4 JVM) generates a stacktrace

Tags: java, oracle10g, itext

I merge different pdfs together with itext 2.1.3. When I am in Eclipse with a 1.6 jvm version everything works fine. However when I try to run on a 10G database (JVM 1.4) I get an error. It is doing this since we have a new version of a certain file. The error is targed on this line :

```
List bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader);
```

The stacktrace is :

```
message : essage: null
StackTrace: 
java.nio.charset.Charset Charset.java class$ (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset$1 Charset.java <init> (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset Charset.java providers (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset Charset.java access$000 (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset$2 Charset.java run (-1)
java.security.AccessController AccessController.java doPrivileged (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset Charset.java lookupViaProviders (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset Charset.java lookup (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset Charset.java isSupported (-1)
java.lang.StringCoding StringCoding.java lookupCharset (-1)
java.lang.StringCoding StringCoding.java decode (-1)
java.lang.String String.java <init> (-1)
java.lang.String String.java <init> (-1)
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfEncodings null convertToString (-1)
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfString null toUnicodeString (-1)
com.lowagie.text.pdf.SimpleBookmark null bookmarkDepth (-1)
com.lowagie.text.pdf.SimpleBookmark null bookmarkDepth (-1)
com.lowagie.text.pdf.SimpleBookmark null getBookmark (-1)
ConsolidationDemande2 ConsolidationDemande2 consoliderDemande2 (1099)
ConsolidationDemande2 ConsolidationDemande2 consoliderDemande2 (109)
Cause by: Message: java/nio/charset/spi/CharsetProvider
StackTrace: 
java.lang.Class Class.java forName0 (-1)
java.lang.Class Class.java forName (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset Charset.java class$ (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset$1 Charset.java <init> (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset Charset.java providers (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset Charset.java access$000 (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset$2 Charset.java run (-1)
java.security.AccessController AccessController.java doPrivileged (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset Charset.java lookupViaProviders (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset Charset.java lookup (-1)
java.nio.charset.Charset Charset.java isSupported (-1)
java.lang.StringCoding StringCoding.java lookupCharset (-1)
java.lang.StringCoding StringCoding.java d
```

Can you help ?

Thanks.

Pierrick

Comment: I doubt that anyone can help you without having access to your specific environment. Furthermore, the iText version you are using is really old (I know it's the one that works in 1.4, but still...) and I don't think that even itextsoftware is available for paid support for such version.

Comment: @PauloSoares is correct. Oracle no longer supports JVM 1.4 and iText Group no longer supports iText 2.1.3. Your company should invest in an upgrade of its legacy systems. If its systems would be audited, the auditing report will high-light different failures.